# Split multiple images in a string

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am using Simple HTML Dom, to grab images from a link, and insert the link to those images in to a MYSQL database.  This all works fine, except where there are multiple images on that link and then all of the links get inserted in to one mysql row.

What i am trying to do is split the links and insert them in to individual rows.

```
$html = file_get_html("$link");
$pic = "";  
foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
     $pic .= $e->outertext ;        
     $linksArray = explode(',', $pic);
     foreach($linksArray as $link) {
          echo "$link"; echo "$id";  
      }
```

So when i run the code above, it will display multiple images and then the id, and not a single image and id, multiple times.

Comment: What is `$link`? Variables don't need to be quoted.

Comment: `$id` is never defined.

Comment: You also append `$pic` on every iteration so you're reexploding the same result multiple times.

Comment: My mistake the first $link is the URL which is taken from a database, $Id is also a variable taken from a database and the code above is just the area of the problem, without me posting all of the code.  Ok so I see what you mean about reexploding the $pic